# Kotlin native multiplatform

Tags: kotlin

I would like to create multiplatform Kotlin Native app. I've seen couple of examples, where we have following structure:

- ...-common (kotlin-platform-common)
- ...-ios (konan plugin)
- ...-jvm (kotlin-platform-jvm)

I would like to read some config from file. There are samples that do that in Kotlin Native. Samples use libraries:

- kotlinx.cinterop.*
- platform.posix.*

Questions:

- Is common module - kotlin native module?
- Can I use this libs in common module?
- Would they compile to code native to iOS? Or this libs could be used only in platform modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C interop and the POSIX functions are exclusive to Kotlin/Native and cannot be used in common modules.